# Convert list object into array

Tags: javascript

I have a list object

```js
{
  value: 5,
  rest: {
    value: 10,
    rest: {
      value: 15,
      rest: null
    }
  }
}
```

that should be converted into array. I was trying to iterate through the list to take the values and push them into array.

```
function listToArr(obj){
let arr = []
    for (let val in object){
        arr.push(Object.values(val))
    }
    return arr
}
```

But I am getting `[ [ 'v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' ], [ 'r', 'e', 's', 't' ] ]`

Comment: `for..in` will iterate through the object's keys, here `value` and `rest`, and a string is an array of characters, or object of pairs of index-character, which lead to your unexpeceted result above. what is your expected output in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ES6 style approach:

```js
let listToArr = (obj) => obj.rest ? [obj.value, ...listToArr(obj.rest)] : [obj.value];

console.log(listToArr({ value: 5, rest: { value: 10, rest: { value: 15, rest: null } } }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to reassign the object inside a loop and access its `value` property:

```js
console.log(listToArr({ value: 5, rest: { value: 10, rest: { value: 15, rest: null } } }));

function listToArr(obj){
  const arr = [];
  while (obj.rest) {
    arr.push(obj.value);
    obj = obj.rest;
  }
  arr.push(obj.value);
  return arr;
}
```

Since the keys are static, using `Object.values` or `for..in` doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Nice, however a nitpick would be not to mutate the argument.

Comment: The argument is not getting mutated. This would work just fine in React, for example.

Comment: Fair enough, I can see use cases for and against this lint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice recursive solution for this as well. Something like:

```js
let a = {
  value: 5,
  rest: {
    value: 10,
    rest: {
      value: 15,
      rest: null
    }
  }
}

function listToArr(obj, arr){
    arr = arr || [];
    if (!obj) return arr;
    return listToArr(obj.rest, arr.concat(obj.value));
}
console.log(listToArr(a));
```